# How do I use datatable child row without ajax?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using the datatable example of child rows without the ajax and im having a problem where my child rows all have the same data. I want to show the data of each row in the child table but its giving me error when I use the laravel code in the function format section. I am using laravel MVC format so I don't need ajax to load data.

```js
    
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:20px;">'+
        '<table class="table table-bordered">'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<th>'+
                    "Product Name"+
                '</th>'+
                '<th>'+
                    "Quantity"+
                '</th>'+
            '</tr>'+                
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+
                    "Item id here"+
                '</td>'+
                '<td>'+
                    "Item data here"+
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>';
}

$('#manageOrderTable tbody button').on('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = t.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

```html
<tbody>
    @php 
    $x=0; 
    @endphp
    @foreach ($orders as $order)                                  
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{$order->order_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_contact}}</td>
        <td class="details-control">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                <b>Items : </b> {{$item_count["$x"]}} 
            </button>
            Item Id: @for ($y = 0; $y < $item_count["$x"]; $y++)
                    {{$item_list["$y"]->product_id}}
                @endfor      
        </td>
        @if ($order->payment_status==1)
        <td><label class="label label-success">Full Payment</label></td>
        @elseif($order->payment_status==2)
        <td><label class="label label-info">Advance Payment</label></td>
        @else
        <td><label class="label label-warning">No Payment</label></td>
        @endif
        <td>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{{route('orders.edit',$order->order_id)}}" id="editOrderModalBtn"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                
                <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" id="paymentOrderModalBtn" data-target="#paymentOrderModal" data-due="{{$order->due}}" data-id="{{$order->order_id}}"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> Payment</a></li>

                <li><a type="button" onclick="printOrder({{$order->order_id}})"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print </a></li>
                
                
                <li><a href="{{route('orderDelete',$order->order_id)}}" type="button"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Remove</a></li>       
              </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @php
    $x++;
    @endphp
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching something about your question, but I found this:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'responsive': true
    });

    // Handle click on "Expand All" button
    $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Expand row details
        table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
    });

    // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
    $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Collapse row details
        table.rows('.parent').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<h3><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/">jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows</a> <small>Responsive extension</small></h3>

<button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Expand All</button>
<button id="btn-hide-all-children" type="button">Collapse All</button>
<hr>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th class="none">Age</th>
            <th class="none">Start date</th>
            <th class="none">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/2u650u18/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=2u650u18)

Hope this help to you.
Regards.